# How Can I Use the sed Command to Replace /home/user With ~

Tags: sed, pwd

Suppose this is the output of `pwd`:

```
/home/amarakon/.local/src/amarakon/scripts/src
```

How can I change it to this:

```
~/.local/src/amarakon/scripts/src
```

I tried this command:

```
pwd | sed 's|/home/.*|~|'
```

But this it the output:

```
~
```

Answer (score 3):

If using `zsh`, you can use:

```
print -P '%~'
```

To get the current working directory with your home directory replaced with `~`. It will also replace `/home/directory/of/otheruser` with `~otheruser`, if `/home/directory/of/otheruser` is `otheruser`'s home directory and `~otheruser` has been expanded before.

You'd normally put `%~` in your `$PROMPT` to get the current working directory there. The `-P` option of `print` enables prompt expansion for that builtin.

Prompt expansion can also be done upon parameter expansion with the `%` parameter expansion flag:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(%):-%~}
```

That `~` replacement can also be enabled with the `D` parameter expansion flag, so you could also do:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(D)PWD}
```

You could also do it by hand with:

```
set -o extendedglob
printf '%s\n' ${PWD/#%(#b)$HOME(|\/*)/\~$match[1]}
```

Though beware that if `$HOME` has symlinks or `.` path components, or `$PWD` has symlink components, that may not work properly as you'd end up with the variables containing different representations of your home.

Doing it with `sed` would  be cumbersome if wanting to do it for arbitrary values of `$HOME`. You'd need to [escape `/` and regex operators in it first](/q/129059) (`.` being a regex operator and common in user names), do it in the `C` locale as dir paths are not guaranteed to be text, load up all the lines of `$PWD` into the pattern space, do the substitution only at the start and only if followed by `/` or the end of the subject:

```
escaped_HOME=$(printf '%s\n' ~ | LC_ALL=C sed '
  :1
  $!{
    N
    b1
  }
  s:[][\\/.^$*]:\\&:g
  s/\n/\\n/g'
)
pwd | LC_ALL=C sed '
  :1
  $!{
    N
    b1
  }
  s/^'"$escaped_HOME"'\(\(\/.*\)\{0,1\}\)$/~\1/'
```

Not the best tool for that. With `perl`:

```
perl -MCwd -le 'print getcwd =~ s|^\Q$ENV{HOME}\E(?![^/])|~|r'
```

If `$HOME` is `/` as it often is for some system users, `%~` will not replace `/` with `~` nor `/dir` with `~/dir` which is probably just as well. The manual ones will replace `/` with `~`, but not `/dir` with `~/dir` which I'd consider acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, substituting whatever matches `/home/.*` with `~` will replace the whole string in the example you show since `.*` matches to the very end of the string.

The variable `PWD` will also hold the current directory's path, and we may use a *much* cheaper parameter substitution on that value:

```bash
[[ "$PWD/" == "${HOME%/}/"* ]] && printf '~%s\n' "${PWD#"${HOME%/}"}"
```

This tests whether `$PWD` contains `$HOME` at the start, and if so, prints `$PWD` with that part replaced by `~`. This is much quicker as it does not require expensive (relatively slow to run) external utilities.

More portably:

```bash
case $PWD/ in ("${HOME%/}/"*) printf '~%s\n' "${PWD#"${HOME%/}"}"; esac
```

Comment: You'd get `~/` when HOME == PWD == /, but I guess that's acceptable. Not doing any substitution when HOME == / as zsh's `%~` does is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

`.` matches any character, so it'll match everything left on the line including the later slashes and path parts.

You basically want to limit that part of the pattern to a series of things that aren't slashes, so it stops the substitution when it encounters a slash (if it does):

```
pwd | sed 's|/home/[^/]*|~|'
```

You might consider requiring `'/home'` to be at the start in case you ever have subfolders named `home` outside of the root folder:

```
pwd | sed 's|^/home/[^/]*|~|'
```

That should work with the output of pwd, but if you're replacing $HOME with ~ in longer strings, you might keep it the first way.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but you can use string operators for that purpose:

```
$ pwd
/home/kali/Documents
```

```
$ [ -z "${PWD%%$HOME*}" ] && echo ${PWD/$HOME/'~'} || echo $PWD
~/Documents
```

---

```
$ pwd
/etc/systemd/network
```

```
$ [ -z "${PWD%%$HOME*}" ] && echo ${PWD/$HOME/'~'} || echo $PWD
/etc/systemd/network
```

---

```
$ pwd
/tmp/home/kali/Documents
```

```
$ [ -z "${PWD%%$HOME*}" ] && echo ${PWD/$HOME/'~'} || echo $PWD
/tmp/home/kali/Documents
```

Now, you specifically asked about `sed`, I don't think it's the best tool or even necessary but you'd do:

```
$ pwd | sed "s|^$HOME|~|"
~/Documents
```

Comment: Your approach with `${PWD%%$HOME*}` would give the wrong result for users whose username is the prefix of another user's username (e.g. for `vic` if there was any other user who's username started with `vic`).